# Adding 'language-highlighting' tag to a question, necessary?

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging, syntax-highlighting

Consider [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/860555/how-do-i-bulk-change-indentation-sizes/860725#860725).

I provided an answer with a bash script. I *did* remember to add embedded [Prettify language hints](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/160921). The highlighting didn't get turned on. Then I found [this post on Meta SE explaining changes to syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting).

So I edited the question to add the `[bash]` tag. Now I'm wondering:

1. Is that a good idea, adding a tag when the question doesn't explicitly limit the solution?
2. Is adding a tag really necessary to turn on syntax highlighting? Remember that I've peppered my answer with language hints.
3. The 'preview' of Q & A (prior to tag-change being approved) *still* didn't show syntax highlighting. Is that by design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your language hints had a typo ("languange" instead of "language"), hence the syntax highlighting didn't get activated.

Comment: Aaargh! Did not see that... I think I need a new pair of glasses >.< ... thanks for fixing it, @Sathya!